# reCaptcha and Silverstripe

Tags: recaptcha, silverstripe

I implemented Recaptcha to Silverstripe and it seems to work.
The only problem is that the formular and the captcha code are at the very end of the page and if you type in a wrong code then the page reloads and jumps back to the top so that the user doesn´t see the formular and captcha code anymore.

how can i make the window not to scroll to the top after entering a wrong captcha code?

Answer (score 4):

Since the HTTP spec doesn't allow to a serverside redirection including an anchor tag, you'll need to use JavaScript to accomplish this. Since the field is highlighted with a validation message in the standard SilverStripe form rendering, you can use this to determine the state of the field once the submitted form loads again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var captchaEl = jQuery('#MyCaptcha');
    if(captchaEl.find('.message.required').length) {
        window.scrollTo(0, captchaEl.scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: [off topic] hey, great to see some silverstripe core developers over here at stackoverflow! thumbs up ;)

Comment: Hey Ingo, thx for your answer. Unfortunatley those state css classes only seem to appear standard input fields but not for the recpatcha field.

Comment: Zooly, I assume you've adjusted the #MyCaptcha selector to whatever it's called in your own form, right? Its pretty plain jQuery, so you should be able to adapt this general pattern to your needs.